# InDesign/CEP: The automatic launch of the extension at application startup does not work

Tags: javascript, manifest, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-extension

I found this thread that is supposed to work: https://community.adobe.com/t5/exchange-discussions/auto-launch-extension-at-application-startup-indesign/m-p/10563054

So I applied the code in the manifest of my extension but it doesn't work. My extension does not start when I open InDesign..

I found this event that works for Photoshop:

```
 <Event>com.adobe.csxs.events.AppOnline</Event>
```

Here my code:

```
<Extension Id="com.my.panel">
  <DispatchInfo>
    <Resources>
      <!-- 4) -->
      <MainPath>./client/index.html</MainPath>
      <!-- 5) -->
      <ScriptPath>./host/index.jsx</ScriptPath>
      <CEFCommandLine />
    </Resources>
    <Lifecycle>
      <AutoVisible>true</AutoVisible>
       <StartOn>
          <!-- PS dispatches this event on startup -->
          <Event>applicationActivate</Event>
          <!-- PPro dispatches this event on startup -->
          <Event>com.adobe.csxs.events.ApplicationActivate</Event>
          <Event>com.adobe.csxs.events.AppOnline</Event>
      </StartOn>
    </Lifecycle>
  </DispatchInfo>
</Extension>
```

I don't see what I did more or less than the answer on the other thread.

**!!! Of course, I tried without the StartOn tags !!!**

Thank you in advance!